# Javascript function for each double or triple words in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have some javascript to run a function for each seperate word in a string:

```
var input = 'this is some text';
var words = input.split(' ');
$.each(words,function(i){
    //Do something
});
```

But how would I do something similar to run the function for each pair of words in a string? Like this:

- this is
- is some
- some text

Or even triple words:

- this is some
- is some text

Comment: do you mean split on a comma? `words = input.split(',');`

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald no split on spaces, the commas I used was just to indicate the separation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common `for` loop instead of using a `foreach` loop

```
var words = "this is some text".split(' ');

// take the words 2 by 2
for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; ++i) {
    var currentWord = words[i],
        nextWord = words[i + 1];

    // do something
}

// take the words 3 by 3
for (var i = 1; i < words.length - 1; ++i) {
    var previousWord = words[i - 1],
        currentWord = words[i],
        nextWord = words[i + 1];

    // do something
}
```

You can also handle the general case.

```
var PACKET_SIZE = 2;
var words = "this is some text".split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i <= words.length - PACKET_SIZE; ++i) {
    var packet = words.slice(i, i + PACKET_SIZE);

    // do something
}
```

Edit: Added greater than or equals to so that the last set of words is also included.

Comment: Nice answer - prefer not to use regex because I will be covering large bodies of text :)

Comment: i <= words.length is better as it includes the last set of words

Comment: Question though - you have words.slice(i, i + PACKET_SIZE) which returns "this,is,some".....how would I get packet = "this is some"?

Comment: You can join the array again. `words.slice(i, i + PACKET_SIZE).join(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Just a proposal with one loop.

```js
function getN(array, n) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
        i + n <= aa.length && result.push(aa.slice(i, i + n).join(' '));
    });
    return result;
}

var input = 'this is some text',
    array = input.split(' ');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getN(array, 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getN(array, 3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or with a callback for reduce

```js
function getN(n) {
    return function (r, a, i, aa) {
        i + n <= aa.length && r.push(aa.slice(i, i + n).join(' '));
        return r;
    };
}

var input = 'this is some text',
    array = input.split(' ');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array.reduce(getN(1), []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array.reduce(getN(2), []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array.reduce(getN(3), []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @ Nina Scholz How you do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop with an increment of 2 or 3:

```
for( var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 2 ) {
  //Do something with words[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var input = 'this is some text';
var words = input.split(' ');
var length = 2;
var str;
$.each(words, function(j) {
  str = "";
  for (i = 0; i < length && (j + i) < words.length; i++) {
    str += " " + words[j + i];
  }
  $("#container").append("<div>" + str + "</div>");
});
```

you can change the pattern length by changing the value of the `length` parameter.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/213/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is using the `split` function to give you an array of words, then applies `map` to transform it into an array of arrays, each the size of **n**. The `join` function is used to turn those arrays into space separated strings again.

```js
var s="this is some text made of several words";
var n=2;
var result = s.split(' ').map(function(val,index,arr) {
    return arr.slice(index,index+n).join(' ');
});
alert(result);
```

And if you don't want the groups of words less than **n**, the ones at the end of the word, you need a bit more code:

```js
var s = "this is some text made of several words";
var n = 3;
var arr = s.split(' ');
var result = arr.slice(0, arr.length - n + 1)
  .map(function(val, index) {
    return arr.slice(index, index + n).join(' ');
  });
alert(result);
```